# Positioning table scrollbar on my body element

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'd like to implement a scrollbar on my table builds with DIVS... I'd like to add a scroll-y bar only for my body element...

It works for the entire table but not for my body element...

JSFiddle : [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/tonymx227/76qxy04k/)

My code :

```css
.scroll{
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.table{
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.header{
    display: table-header-group;
    background-color: green;
}

.header .row{
    display: table-row;
}

.header .row .cell{
    display: table-cell;
}

.body{
    display: table-row-group;
    background-color: red;
}

.body .row{
    display: table-row;
}

.body .row .cell{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<p>some content here</p>       
<div class="grid5">
          <div class="grid">
            <div class="wrap">
              <div class="scroll">
                <div class="table">
                  <div class="header">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="cell">Colonne</div>
                      <div class="cell">Colonne</div>
                      <div class="cell">Colonne</div>
                      <div class="cell">Colonne</div>
                      <div class="cell">Colonne</div>
                      <div class="cell">Colonne</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```css
.scroll{
    height: 200px;

}

.table{
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.header{
    display: table-row;
    background-color: green;
}

.header .row{
    display: table-row;
}

.header .row .cell{
    display: table-cell;
}

.body{
  
    background-color: red;
    height:200px;
    overflow-y:auto;
       

}

.body .row{
    display: table-row;
}

.body .row .cell{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<p>some content here</p>       
<div class="grid5">
          <div class="grid">
            <div class="wrap">
              <div class="scroll">
                <div class="table">
                  <div class="header">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="cell">Colonne</div>
                      <div class="cell">Colonne</div>
                      <div class="cell">Colonne</div>
                      <div class="cell">Colonne</div>
                      <div class="cell">Colonne</div>
                      <div class="cell">Colonne</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The scroll-y works perfectly but if I modify the text content of a cell in the header, cells don't get the same width...

Comment: You have to set same width:- `.body .row .cell` , `.header .row .cell` try once.

Comment: Yes but I don't want to set the width... Because this is a feature for a table of XXXXXXXXXXX lines generated in Javascript...

Comment: Okay then try it:-.body {
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 550px;
}

Comment: Doesn't work too... If I modify the text content of a column I get the same problem...